# Is an ion or a polar molecule more attracted to water in general?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, water

I realize that there are exceptions but as a general rule of thumb, is an ion or a polar molecule attracted to water? I think that it would be ions since the charge is much larger than the net dipole of polar molecules but I can't find anything definitive regarding this.

Comment: An ion or dipole is not 'attracted to water' in the sense that a piece of iron is attracted to a magnet. Possibly what you ask is whether a polar molecule or an ion is energetically more favourable to dissolve in  a  polar solvent (water, acetonitrile etc) vs. a non-polar solvent, such as hexane or benzene.

Comment: @porphyrin Hm, If we consider force being proportional to the gradient of potential energy=f{distance),, ions and water molecules are mutually attracted. It is similar as for atoms forming bonds. But this attraction is short range and weakens rapidly with distance.

Comment: @Poutnik,  I think that I had my pedants hat on;  of course you are right but I meant attracted to water molecules not water per se. In a liquid there always has to be multiple attractions otherwise its a gas/vapour, so I thought that thinking about energy was more helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, ions are more attracted to water ( in sense of favourable energy state), due bigger and more localized charge, compared to polar molecules.

But, ions are often even more than to water attracted to other molecules or ions, forming charged or neutral complexes, or precipitates.